# pass parameter from View to Controller in asp mvc

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am trying to pass parameter from view to controller,

**This is my View:**

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
{
  @foreach (var pricedetails in ViewBag.PriceTotal)
  {
    <div style="text-align:center; clear:both ">
      <h5 class="product-title">@pricedetails.Title</h5>
    </div>
    <div class="product-desciption" style="height:40px">@pricedetails.Descriptions</div>                         
    <p class="product-desciption product-old-price"> @pricedetails.PricePoints</p>
    <div class="product-meta">
      <ul class="product-price-list">
        <li>
          <span class="product-price">@pricedetails.PricePoints</span>
        </li>
        <li>
          <span class="product-save">Get This Free</span>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="product-actions-list">
        <input type="submit" name='giftid' value="Get Gift"
           onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("Index",  new { id = pricedetails.PriceId })'" />
      </ul>
    </div>
  }     
}
```

**my action method:**

On submit it reaches the Action Method, but I am not able to get the PriceId for each Price

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(int id=0) // here PriceId is not passed on submit
{
  List<Price_T> priceimg = (from x in dbpoints.Price_T
                            select x).Take(3).ToList(); ;
  ViewBag.PriceTotal = priceimg;
  var allpoint = singletotal.AsEnumerable().Sum(a => a.Points);
  var price = from x in dbpoints.Price_T
              where x.PriceId == id
              select x.PricePoints;
  int pricepoint = price.FirstOrDefault();
  if (allpoint < pricepoint)
  {             
    return Content("<script language='javascript' type='text/javascript'>alert('You are not elgible');</script>");
  }
  else
  {
    return Content("<script language='javascript' type='text/javascript'>alert('You are elgible');</script>");
  }
  return View("Index");
}
```

**Url Routing:**

```
routes.MapRoute(
  name: "homeas",
  url: "Index/{id}",
  defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);

routes.MapRoute(
  name: "Default",
  url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
  defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

May I know what wrong I am doing ?

Comment: what you are doing is entirely incorrect. you cannot use onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("Index",  new { id = pricedetails.PriceId })'" to submit to a POST method

Comment: You don't have any controls in your form! and why are you doing both a submit and redirect?

Comment: @frebin francis, thank you, ok i will remove the form but how can pass PriceId to Action method

Comment: @stom do not remove the form. what you need to do is put that price id in a hidden field and set name="PriceId" and in your controller change the name of parameter id to PriceId (this is just for readability purpose) and remove the onclick method from the button.

Comment: And then you may as well delete all the code in the action method since all you do is return a script - `return View();` is never executed! What is the actual point of this code?

Comment: @StephenMuecke, here user clicks on some product, i pass the  product PriceId to action method and then do some calculation and alert him weather he is eligible to buy or not

Comment: Then use ajax to call a method that returns a json result indicating if successful, then update the DOM or display a message

Comment: @frebin francis, you mean after for each, @Html.Hidden("PriceId", pricedetails.), but after dot i am not able to get PriceId, if possible can you show how i can?

Comment: @stom do you want that "get gift" button for all price details ?

Comment: @frebin francis, yes thats what i need

Comment: @stom so you have to rewrite the UI. you need to create form for the each price details, so just create the form inside the foreach loop.

Comment: @frebinfrancis, The action result is not modifying any data so it should be a GET (a form is not required and it not appropriate)

Comment: then it will be easy, just put a actionlink method instead of button

Comment: @frebin francis, when i use just action link, View uses Priceid as page index and redirects to localhost:21747/Index/23, but i need to alert user before redirect , if possible can you post an example

Comment: @stom just wait for 5 mins i am creating one sample.

Comment: @stom  i just posted the sample solution. please refer it below. any doubts  you can ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use the following in your cshtml page

```
  @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        @Html.ActionLink(item.PriceDetails, "GetGift", new { priceID = item.priceID }, new { @class = "lnkGetGift" })
    }

    <script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("a.lnkGetGift").on("click", function (event) {                   
                event.preventDefault();
               $.get($(this).attr("href"), function (isEligible) {
                if (isEligible) {
                    alert('eligible messsage');
                }
else
{
alert('not eligible messsage');
}
            })
            });
        });
    </script>
```

and in controller

```
     [HttpGet]
                public JsonResult GetGift(int priceID)
                {
 List<Price_T> priceimg = (from x in dbpoints.Price_T
                            select x).Take(3).ToList(); ;
  ViewBag.PriceTotal = priceimg;
  var allpoint = singletotal.AsEnumerable().Sum(a => a.Points);
  var price = from x in dbpoints.Price_T
              where x.PriceId == id
              select x.PricePoints;
  int pricepoint = price.FirstOrDefault();
  if (allpoint < pricepoint)
  {             
    return Json(false, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
  }
  else
  {
    return Json(true, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
  }
                }
```

Please change your parameters according to the method param and price entity
Hope this helps.

Comment: This is doing a redirect an empty page that will just display an alert! I doubt that what OP wants.

Comment: @frebin francis,ya  that's what i need

Comment: i am changing my answer plase wait for 2 mins ?

Comment: @Stephen Mueck, appreciate, as you said the redirect resulted in empty page, like this http://localhost:21747/Index/23

Comment: @stom, Your approaching this all wrong. The calculations should be done in the initial GET method. If the user is 'not eligible' (whatever that means) then why would you even display the product with a button that redirects them to the product - its a terrible user experience.

Comment: @Stephen Muecke, its not a redirect, but an alert, its reward based program for online users

Comment: @frebin francis, i am newbie to mvc, and i am so thankful to you for the time spent, its working fine

Comment: In a previous comment you stated _redirects to localhost:21747/Index/23, but i need to alert user before redirect_. So which is it?

Comment: @Stephen Mueke, i mean, actually it was redirecting when clicked, but i expected to alert when i clicked but now @ frebin francis has solved the issue, thank you.

Comment: @stom <li> <a class="lnkGetGift" href="@Url.Action("GetGift", new { id = price.PriceId })"><i class="fa fa-mobile">@price.PriceDescription</i></a>
        </li> is this what u wanted?

Comment: frebin francis, can you help me with this,  <li><a href="@Url.Action("GetGift", new { id = price.PriceId })"><i class="fa fa-mobile"></i> My Gift</a></li>, how can i use new { @class = "lnkGetGift" } with Url.Action

Comment: you can set css class directly to the <a> tag no need to use it with Url.Action. see my previous comment.

Comment: hi, in your jquery i am trying to redirect to another view and display the selected product based on Priceid,  if (isEligible) {
window.location.href = "@Url.Action("RedeemGift", new { id = here  how to get on click the selected Price Id})";

Comment: You can add a hidden field inside <a> tag and get hidden field value on that link click event.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you get rid of the `Html.BeginForm()`. Just leave the `for...loop` and define your "Get Gift" button like this:

```
<input type="button" id='giftid' name='giftid' value="Get Gift" onclick="getGift(@(pricedetails.PriceId))'" />
```

Then, at the bottom of the view file where the `Get Gift` button is located, define some JavaScript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function getGift(priceId) {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: '@Url.Action("Index", "Home")',
            data: { priceId: priceId },
            contentType : "json",
            success:function(data){    
              // Do whatever in the success.
            },
            error:function(){    
              // Do whatever in the error.
            }
        });
</script>
```

By using an ajax call to get the gift data, you don't have to submit anything. This makes things a lot easier in your case. Pressing the `Get Gift` button simply makes an ajax call.

I don't have time to try this out myself, but hopefully the above example should get you up and running.

EDIT:

I've managed to sneak in some time to come up with an example.

```
Controller

public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var items = new List<int>();
        items.Add(1);
        items.Add(2);
        items.Add(3);

        return View(items);
    }

    public ActionResult GetGift(int priceId)
    {
        return RedirectToAction("Index"); // You'll be returning something else.
    }
}
```

View

```
@model List<int>

@foreach (var price in Model)
{
    <input type="button" id='giftid' name='giftid' value="Get Gift" onclick="getGift(@(price))" />
}

<script type="text/javascript">
    function getGift(priceId) {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: '@Url.Action("GetGift", "Home")',
            data: { priceId: priceId },
            contentType: "json",
            success: function(data) {
                // Do whatever in the success.
            },
            error: function() {
                // Do whatever in the error.
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

Hope this helps you.

Comment: @appreciate your effort, i am new to ajax i have to give a try

Answer (score 0):

I think you should correct here

```
<input type="button" name='giftid' value="Get Gift"
       onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("Index",  new { id = pricedetails.PriceId })'" />
```

Comment: @Praves Kawser, when i use button, View uses Priceid as page index and redirects to http://localhost:21747/Index/23, but i need to alert user before redirect